# Low throughput using jdbc query on voltdb

Tags: jdbc, voltdb

Using jdbc query data,  The throughput is about 10000+/s when the where condition  contain partition column, No partition column that the throughput is only 300+/s.
Could you give me advise,pls

Comment: Welcome to SO, in order to someone help you, you need to share more details about question, such as code samples at least , and if possible logs, environment etc..

Comment: VoltDB here. Can you provide the DDL for the table(s) involved, and any indexes you created? Are you calling a procedure or a SQL statement? How many threads are you using in your client using JDBC? There are a lot of variables that affect throughput. It's normal for a single-partition transaction to perform better than a multi-partition transaction, but how much depends on a number of things. We need more details to help.